# Extracting first token from a delimeted string

Tags: c#, string

i have a string:
e.g. `WORD1_WORD2_WORD3`

how do i get just WORD1 from the string?
i.e the text before the first underscore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
YOUR_STRING.Split('_')[0]
```

In fact the Split method returns an array of strings resulting from splitting the original string at any occurrence of the specified character(s), not including the character at which the split was performed.

Comment: As Mark pointed out, this is a very inefficient way of doing this.

Comment: It's just the most straightforward way to do this, the most intuitive and unless the application is performance-critical and repeats that operation over and over again it won't really matter. Anyway I agree that's not the solution with the lowest execution time :)

Comment: make sure to add some validation, that there is actual a '_' in the string, if you do it dynamically later :-)

Answer (score 11):

It may be tempting to say `Split` - but that involves the creating of an array and lots of individual strings. IMO, the optimal way here is to find the first underscore, and take a substring:

```
string b = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_')); // assumes at least one _
```

(edit)

If you are doing this lots, you could add some extension methods:

```
public static string SubstringBefore(this string s, char value) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
    int i = s.IndexOf(value);
    return i > 0 ? s.Substring(0,i) : s;
}
public static string SubstringAfter(this string s, char value) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
    int i = s.IndexOf(value);
    return i >= 0 ? s.Substring(i + 1) : s;
}
```

then:

```
string s = "a_b_c";
string b = s.SubstringBefore('_'), c = s.SubstringAfter('_');
```

Answer (score 7):

if *s* is the string:

```
int idx = s.IndexOf('_');

if (idx >= 0)
  firstPart = s.Substring(0,idx);
```

Comment: +1 because we don't have the problems that .Split() can cause

Answer (score 1):

`("WORD1_WORD2_WORD3").Split('_')[0]`

should return "WORD1". If it doesn't work try .Spilt() on a string variable with the Content you specified.

```
string str="WORD1_WORD2_WORD3";
string result=str.Split('_')[0];
```

This actually returns an array:

```
{"WORD1", "WORD2", "WORD3"}
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets around the string, you can just do "".Split('_')[0];

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. You can use Split, Substring. etc. An example with Split:

String var = "WORD1_WORD2_WORD3";

String result = var.Split('_')[0];